# how to split string in python by string.pronunciation and string.whitespace at the same time

Tags: python, list, split

i write this code:

```
import re
import string

new_string = re.split(string.pronunciation|string.whitespace, string)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `new_string = re.split('[%s]' % (string.punctuation + string.whitespace), 'Some. String')`

As you can see in your error message, operator `|` is unsupported for `str`s and you might mistyped `punctuation` as `pronunciation`.

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 641, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position 10 (line 1, column 11)